# Changed a page from ASPX to HTM(L) but IIS points to ASPX regardless

Tags: asp.net, html, iis-6

We recently rewrote our company homepage and have come across a peculiar error.  We have very few pages that need any code behind them, so we wrote the website in static HTML served out of IIS6.  The few pages that need any code (Contact Us, with a contact form, for instance) are .ASPX pages.

The previous version of the website had more .ASPX pages, even if there was no code in the code-behind. One of those pages was "management.aspx", and in the new site this is, logically enough, "management.htm".  We're smart enough to not just change the file extension -- we rewrote everything, it just has the name in common.

Here's the peculiar part:  Even though every link in the entire website points to "management.htm", IIS6 continues to try and serve "manangement.aspx".  I've reset IIS, stopped/started the Default Web Site under IIS6, deleted pages from "Temporary ASP.NET Files" and deleted out temporary GZIP files from the server as well. This isn't MVC or anything, so we have no explicit URL routing, and while I can see us having to implement static file handling in our web.config httpHandlers, I can't imaging that being a necessity.

What gives? Why is IIS6 still trying to serve the old "management.aspx" page when we're explicitly asking for "management.htm"? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Is the file correctly renamed? Look at it from DOS prompt. Could it be management.htm.aspx? Sounds silly, but see if that is the problem.

Comment: No sweat - it's correctly named .htm .

Comment: Is .HTM mapped to be served by asp.net in IIS?

Comment: No.  IIS is serving .HTM files like normal without going to aspnet_isapi.

Comment: Can you say more about the exact scenario that's failing?  Are you just clicking on a link for management.htm, and then seeing management.aspx in the browser instead?  Or what?

Comment: What does the IIS log show when you try to access management.htm?

Comment: Log entry:

2009-11-17 15:35:40 W3SVC1 10.1.1.101 GET /management.aspx - 80 - 24.173.137.70 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+GTB6;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) 404 0 0

Again, definitely not putting "management.aspx" in the address bar -- IIS is routing "management.htm" to "management.aspx" and then 404ing.  Furthermore, anythingelse.htm gives an IE 404 without trying tou pull up .aspx, so it's definitely routing "management.htm" somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your bindings have to be off somewhere... check top level for *, *.htm, managment.htm, etc.  Then check virtual directories.

If you paste "http://yoursite/management.htm" in your browser and you get a YSOD, this is an IIS issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you still have the bin folder in the root of your site.

Do you get a 404 because it tries to load management.aspx and it's not there?

Comment: Yes, exactly...only its a YSOD because we're not handling the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Default Page on the Website/Virtual directory in Question, and if it exists remove the reference to manangement.aspx.